# Variable initialized with let is not changing?

Tags: javascript

My code is returning an empty array from main and then [foo,bar,baz] on the console log after main is called. Was the original array not changed inside of main? When I remove the arr function both console logs return an empty array. Is it because the function arr is a callback for console? If someone could explain why the function arr is affecting the output that would be great thanks.

```js
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
function main() {
   arr = [];
   function arr() {
      const result= 8
      return result;
    }
   console.log(arr);
}
main();
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Not a good idea to have a variable and function with the same name `arr`. Also, I think you mean "My code is printing an empty array" rather than "My code is returning an empty array".

Comment: You have made too many variables and functions named `arr`, so it is confusing to understand. Maybe try renaming the variables for better readability and expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You created *another* variable named `arr` inside the function, so all references to `arr` inside the function refer to that new variable (which is only scoped to the function), and the outside `arr` remains unchanged. Your code is equivalent to

```js
let arr = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

function main() {
  // new variable for this scope:
  let arr;
  // function declaration is hoisted:
  arr = function arr() {
    const result = 8
    return result;
  }
  // assignment runs:
  arr = [];
  console.log(arr);
}
main();
// but arr outside remains unchanged because it's a different binding
console.log(arr);
```

This is one reason why it's important to give variables meaningful names. A function is not an array, so it probably shouldn't be named `arr` unless you're deliberately trying to confuse readers of the code.

You can also help prevent yourself from making this sort of mistake by using the ESLint rule [`no-shadow`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-shadow), which prevents inner scope variables from having the same name as an outer scope variable.

Comment: This is shown by adding a `console.log(arr);` statement at the beginning of the function. it prints `function arr`, not the outer array.

Comment: `let arr;` is a bad choice